# Entity Framework 5 - code first array navigation property one to many with Interface Type

Tags: ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-5, foreign-key-relationship, navigation-properties

These are my classes:

```
public class Post : IPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int[] DuplicateOf { get; set; }
    public virtual ICommentInfo[] Comments { get; set; }
}

 public class CommentInfo : ICommentInfo
{
    public virtual string Author { get; set; }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual int PostId{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PostId")]
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

With this CommentConfiguration added to OnModelCreate():

```
HasRequired(c => c.Post)
            .WithMany(b=>(ICollection<CommentInfo>) b.Comments)
            .HasForeignKey(b=>b.PostId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

I really cannot understand why the property Comments is always null, and why EF doesn't initialize it since it's virtual. 
I tried disabling lazy loading too, but when i try loading the navigation property with `context.Post.Include("Comments")` an error tells me that "There is not a navigation property called Comments".
So I tried using Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 3 to see the Entity Data Model, and I discovered that there is not a navigation end for table "Post" even if there is the relationship between the two tables and there's the Comment table end too.

I sincerly don't know which way to turn, could be a problem of Array?? Should I use an Icollection property??
Though I cannot change the type of that property because Post is implementing an Interface.

Every sample I look at is clear and easy to make work. Please help me.. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

This is what I changed after looking at the [link](http://antix.co.uk/Blog/EF4-Code-First-and-Interface-Property-Types) I posted yesterday.

```
  public class Post : IPost
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int[] DuplicateOf { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CommentInfo> Comments { get; set; } 
    ICommentInfo[] IPost.Comments { 
      get { return Comments ; } 
      set { Comments = (CommentInfo[])value; } }
  }
```

The exception is: `System.ObjectDisposedException :The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection` and raises when the application tries to get the Comments.
If I remove the `virtual` key the exception disappear but the property remain always null and the values don't persist in any way.

**EDITv2**
I've solved my problem adding a new property and map my old property to it.

```
public class Post : IPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int[] DuplicateOf { get; set; }
    public ICommentInfo[] Comments
    {
        get { return ListComments.ToArray(); }

    }
    public List<CommentInfo> ListComments {get;set;}
}
```

In my PostConfiguration  OnModelCreate() I used the ListComments property as a navigation property like this:

```
HasMany(b => b.ListComments)
                .WithRequired(c=>c.Post)
                .HasForeignKey(c=>c.PostId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Now it perfectly works, it was simpler than I expected and when I try to receive the Comments Collection, if I include the "ListComments" property, I get the array of  Post.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: After spent time, I found that could be a problem of Interface type in my classes. I tried to follow the example here [http://antix.co.uk/Blog/EF4-Code-First-and-Interface-Property-Types] and changed my implementation but now it raise this exception:

System.ObjectDisposedException :The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Comment: OK, but how do you fetch the Posts from the database and where do you first access `IPost.Comments`? You can't do that in one statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't access the link in your comment, but I assume you changed

```
public virtual ICommentInfo[] Comments { get; set; }
```

into the common way to define navigation properties:

```
public virtual ICollection<CommentInfo> Comments { get; set; }
```

because entity framework does not support interfaces in its conceptual model.

The exception about the disposed context means that you access this property after fetching `Post` objects from the database *and* disposing the context. This triggers lazy loading while the connection to the database is lost. The solution is to use [`Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

```
var posts = context.Posts.Include(p => p.Comments).Where(...)
```

Now posts and comments are fetched in one go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer..
This is the [Link](http://antix.co.uk/Blog/EF4-Code-First-and-Interface-Property-Types), sorry.

I know that the solution at my problem is changing the collection property type, but the class Post implements the interface IPost and  I receive the type from it.
I tried the solution in the link, explicitly implementing the Comments property this but raises that exception: 
`public CommentInfo Comments { get; set; }    
    ICommentInfo[] IPost.Comments {
        get { return Comments ; }
        set { Comments = (CommentInfo[])value; }
    }`

Comment: Could you add this piece of code to the question and also the line(s) where the exception is actually raised?