# Inserting JSON file into SQL Server when JSON contains a list

Tags: c#, json, sql-server

I am trying to import a `JSON` file into SQL server via a .Net Core application.

I have set up my classes using the tool in VS which converts a `JSON` doc to classes.  I then used this to create database using the EF Core migration.

I have deserialised the `JSON` into my `RootObject` class using the following:

```
RootObject rootObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonFromFile);
```

I can expand the `RootObject` object and all looks good, I can see each field and it contains the right data.

I then want to insert this data into the database, I currently have:

```
var mySolve = new RootObject
            {
                uuid = rootObject.uuid,
                solution = new Solution { gross_margin = rootObject.solution.myValue, imbalances = rootObject.solution.imbalances  }
            };


            db.RootObjects.Add(mySolve);
            db.SaveChanges();
            db.Dispose();
```

The problem is that the imbalances class is a list in the json file as seen below:

```
"solution": {
        "myValue": 9999.99,
        "imbalances": [
            {
                "commodity": "Value1",
                "name": "Val1",
                "direction": "INPUT",
                "amount": 1.419884
            },
            {
                "commodity": "Value2",
                "name": "Val2",
                "direction": "INPUT",
                "amount": 1.419884
            }
        ]
    }
```

The Class for imbalances in my app looks like this:

```
public class Imbalance
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string commodity { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string direction { get; set; }
        public float amount { get; set; }
    }
```

My app throws an exception on `db.RootObjects.Add(mySolve);` of:

> The type of navigation property 'imbalances' on the entity type
>   'Solution' is 'Imbalance[]' which is an array type. Collection
>   navigation properties cannot be arrays.

How can insert this object into my database?

UPDATE

I have a table for every section in the JSON file as my class library was auto generated from the JSON file.  The imbalances table looks like this:

[image: Imbalances SQL table]

Comment: what does you context look like? have you created a table for the imbalances? do they have id's? you cannot insert an array of anonymous objects in a database.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but I'm not a fan of table named RootObject. Because Json2Csharp named the object that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework 5 - code first array navigation property one to many with Interface Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790960/entity-framework-5-code-first-array-navigation-property-one-to-many-with-inter)

Comment: I think so combined with @nAviD's answer below.  Just testing everything at mo.  I agree with you about the RootObject name and I will be changing it once I move from development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `RootObject` change the type of `Imbalances` property from `Imbalance[]` to `List<Imbalance>` or any class derived from `ICollection`.

Comment: That appears to work, let me do some more testing and I will come back and mark it as the answer if successful